# preg replace with scandic alphabets

Tags: php, preg-replace, character

I have function that strips things from file and I can't get scandic characters working with it.

```
function strip($file_content) {

$match = array("/[^äÄöÖa-zA-Z0-9-+.,&=??????:;*'\"???\/\@\[\]\(\)\s]/","/((\x0D\x0A\s*){3,}|(\x0A\s*){3,}|(\x0D\s*){3,})/", "/\x0D\x0A|\x0A|\x0D/");
$replace = array("-", "<br />\n<br />\n", "<br />\n");
$file_content = preg_replace($match, $replace, trim($file_content));

return $file_content;
}
```

And I echo the content in my web page:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
echo strip(file_get_contents($file));
```

So what is the best solution to get scandic characters working when I echo the file content? (ä-Ö)

Comment: Add `u`(unicode) option to pattern

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Please, add sample input, what you get and expected result.

Comment: All ä and ö was replaced "-".